# Inverting Matricies Python without third-party libraries

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra

### I need to invert a matrix containing floats using python, but without using third party libraries (i.e numpy). What is the least computationally intensive way of inverting matrices in such a manner?

I have attempted to use the fact that the transpose of the cofactor matrix times the reciprocal determinant equals the inverse matrix. However I am farely certain that the recursive method is taking too long:

```
def getMatrixMinor(m,i,j):
    return [row[:j] + row[j+1:] for row in (m[:i]+m[i+1:])]

def getMatrixDeternminant(m):
if len(m) == 2:
    return m[0][0]*m[1][1]-m[0][1]*m[1][0]
    determinant = 0
    for c in range(len(m)):
        determinant += ((-1)**c)*m[0][c]*getMatrixDeternminant(getMatrixMinor(m,0,c))
return determinant

def getMatrixInverse(m):
determinant = getMatrixDeternminant(m)
if len(m) == 2:
    return [[m[1][1]/determinant, -1*m[0][1]/determinant],
            [-1*m[1][0]/determinant, m[0][0]/determinant]]
cofactors = []
for r in range(len(m)):
    cofactorRow = []
    for c in range(len(m)):
        minor = getMatrixMinor(m,r,c)
        cofactorRow.append(((-1)**(r+c)) * getMatrixDeternminant(minor))
    cofactors.append(cofactorRow)
cofactors = transposeMatrix(cofactors)
for r in range(len(cofactors)):
    for c in range(len(cofactors)):
        cofactors[r][c] = cofactors[r][c]/determinant
return cofactors
```

Apologies if the formatting is weird.

Comment: Show some research effort. What does your matrix look like? What are its dimensions? What have _you tried so far_?

Answer (score 0):

Inverting by the adjoint matrix has essentially only theoretical value.

Computationally efficient methods never involve computing determinants and so. Take a look at [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Finding_the_inverse_of_a_matrix), which requires high-school math to understand and is more-or-less the standard starting point for such "endeavors".